# How can I call println when writing a Gradle plugin in Java

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a Gradle plugin in Java, and yes I know I can just use `System.out.println`, or just write it in Groovy.

But I am curious if a direct static `println` function exists in one of the Gradle classes. I could not find one. I'm wonder if there is something like this:

```
package org.gradlerocks;

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;

static import org.gradle.api.Something.println;


public class RockItTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void opine() {
        System.out.println("Yep. Gradle rocks.");

        // this would be groovy/gradle-ish:
        println("Yep. Gradle rocks.");

    }

}
```

I was wondering if there is some Gradle class with a static `println` I could import.

Else I can just write my own static println function. But thought I'd ask the community to see if one already existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such method in the Groovy Development Kit. And I would recommend to not write your own.

Even though you are developing a plugin for Gradle, which naturally works in a Groovy environment, for this project you are using Java. And in Java, you use `System.out.println(...)`. If you want to develop your plugin in a Groovy-ish style, you should use Groovy (e.g. in combination with `@CompileStatic`). While in Groovy it would feel natural to see a simple `println(...)` statement when reading your code, in Java it wouldn't. Readers may get confused or need an extra check, where this method comes from. Or do you add `is(Object)` methods to all your Java classes just to make them look Groovy-ish? Stick to the language you are using and apply its conventions, not the conventions of other languages.

Please note, that even if Groovy adds a lot more automatic imports to your environment, `println(...)` is not a static import, but a [method on `Object`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#println(java.lang.Object)), added as a Groovy JDK enhancement (comparable to `each(Closure)`).

If you ask for the most gradle-ish way to log messages, take a look at [the Gradle docs on logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html):

> Gradle redirects anything written to standard output to its logging system at the QUIET log level.

For a more detailed log experience, your plugin could use the `Logger` instances provided by both the `Project` instance and each `Task` to support logging on different log levels.

Comment: I agree with those points, and I agree `logger.quiet()` is definitely the way to go from Java. Now if we just had access to the StyledText classes. ;-)